# What is the proper protocol for addressing one's title and position in an email signature?

Tags: communication

I am creating an email signature and I am not sure what the protocol should be.

Should it say

> Dr. Locc
>
> Department of Social and Consumer Sciences.

or should my position within the dept. be referenced??

> Dr. Locc
>
> Social and Consumers Science Department Chairman

Comment: What's a dual department head?  Also, it is better to write your question in such a way that the title and the body each stand alone.  As it is, the title doesn't convey your question, and the body is missing important context.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time with this site,  I am the new department head for the Social Science Department as well as the Consumer and Family Science Dept.

Comment: You can use the "Edit" button to clarify your question.

Comment: How about : Dr. Locc Department of Social and Consumer Sciences (Chairperson) ?

Comment: What does your institution's style guide say?

Answer (score 5):

There is no formal protocol for a "signature block." You can put as much or as little as you would ike. If you know the recipient well, for instance, the block is unnecessary. For more formal occasions, however, I would include as much of your affiliation as is appropriate:

> I. M. Professor
>   My Job Title
>   My Department
>   My University
>   Other contact information

If you are chair, I'd indicate that specifically. Instead of the second and third lines, those could be combined as:

> Chair, Department of X

Comment: Are the blank lines intentional or a formatting artefact ...

Comment: @StrongBad I supposed a formatting one. For further cases, you can make the quote formatted as I did if you put `<br>` at the end of each line ;)

Comment: Yes, it was a formatting issue with the Markdown coding.

Answer (score 1):

My signatures are usually of the form:

Name

Title

Official Department Name

University X